# Continuous linear functional on $C^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is a distribution.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, distribution-theory

Prove that every continuous linear functional on $C^{\infty}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is of the form $\Lambda\mapsto\Lambda f$ for some distribution $\Lambda$ with compact support.

I am stuck at this problem, which is a slightly modified version of an exercise from Rudin's Functional Analysis (Ex 19, chapter 6). There is a theorem in the book that states the same conclusion for the space of test functions $D(\Omega)$, but I can't modify its proof for the stated problem.

Any hint would be appreciated.

Comment: isn't $D =  C^\infty_c \subset C^\infty_{loc}$ ? but the problem is the word "continuous" : how do you define continuity on $C^\infty_{loc}$ ? that it converges in the test space sense on every compact ? in that case yes it works well $D \subset C^\infty_{loc}$ in the topological sense

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand what you are saying. I think the continuity is defined by the locally convex topology of $C^{\infty}_{loc}$.

Answer (score 3):

Does Rudin really use the notation $C^\infty_{loc}$? This makes little sense to me; I can't imagine how $C^\infty_{loc}$ could be anything other than $C^\infty$.

First we need to note that taken literally the conclusion makes no sense: By definition a distribution is a (continuous) linear functional on $C^\infty_c$, so there's simply no such thing as $\Lambda f$ for $\Lambda$ a distribution and $f\in C^\infty$.

Say $L$ is a continuous linear functional on $C^\infty$. Saying that $L$ is given by a distribution with compact suppport actually means this: There exists a distribution with compact support $\Lambda$ such that $Lf=\Lambda\phi$ whenever $f\in C^\infty$, $\phi\in C^\infty_c$, and $\phi=f$ on a neighborhood of the support of $\Lambda$.

**Hint:** The topology is uniform convergence of all derivatives on compact sets. That is to say, the topology induced by the seminorms $$\rho_{K,N}(f)=\sup_{x\in K}\sum_{|\alpha|\le N}|D^\alpha f(x)|$$for compact sets $K$ and positive integers $N$. Any finite family of these seminorms is dominated by one of these seminorms; hence there exist $K$, $N$ and $c$ so that $$|L f|\le c\rho_{K,N}(f).$$

Now *define* $\Lambda$ to be the restriction of $L$ to $C^\infty_c$. The hint shows that $\Lambda$ is in fact a distribution with compact support, and also that if $\phi$ is a test function with $\phi=f$ in a neighborhood of $K$ then $Lf=L\phi=\Lambda\phi$.

There was a second hint in the original version of this post:

**Second hint, edited:** For every compact $K$ there exists $\psi\in C^\infty_c$ such that $\psi=1$ on a neighborhood of $K$.

On reflection that's actually irrelevant here; it shows that any distribution with compact support ``is'' a continuous linear functional on $C^\infty$. (If $\Lambda$ is a distibution with compact support define $L:C^\infty\to\mathbb C$ by $Lf=\Lambda(f\psi)$...)

Comment: Thanks for the hints. It is not precisely a problem from the Rudin, rather a modified version of an exercise in chapter 6.

Comment: how will you prove it for continuous linear functional just on $C^\infty$. I am not able to get it from your hints.

Comment: @bunny In your notation/terminology, what is the difference between $C^\infty$ and $C^\infty_{loc}$?

Comment: yes i think they both will be same but after that too i am not able to follow your hints to get to the solution

Comment: @bunny Just realized there was a problem with definitions, hence it was unclear exactly what needs to be proved. Edited answer.

Comment: i think u still need to improve your hints in order to get the solution as how are you able to find fixed compact set $K$ and natural number $N$ which will work for each $f\in C^\infty$

Comment: @bunny Are you familiar with the notion of the topology on a vector space induced by a family of seminorms, and the characterization of continuous linear functionals with respect to such a topology?

Comment: @David C. Ullrich yes

Comment: @bunny Then I don't see what the problem is - as I point out, any finite family of these seminorms is dominated by one of these seminorms;

Comment: Yes for a finite family you will have some dominance but you need a uniform dominant

Comment: @bunny Huh? It's obvious that if $F$ is a finite set of those seminorms then there exists $\rho_{K,N}$ such that $\rho\le\rho_{K,N}$ for every $\rho\in F$. Period.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if the point is that the distribution can be chosen to have compact support. This is true if you consider the functional as acting on functions whose support is contained in a fixed bounded set.